# How to set scrollView delegate from a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that contains a tableView. I want to set its scrollView delegate to self, but I am not sure how to do that? if i call

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

It will set the `UITableViewDelegate` to self, and not the `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A table view delegate is a scroll view delegate, so you have already set it.

```
@protocol UITableViewDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Hm, but what if I'm only interested in the scroll view delegate methods and want to let the super view controller for example handle all the table view stuff, is it a way to solve that?